# How do I specify the encoding in an print() statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, encoding

How do I specify the encoding during a `print()` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

[`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) calls `file.write()`, and `file` defaults to `sys.stdout`. `sys.stdout` is a file object whose [`write()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write) method encodes strings according to its [encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.encoding) property. If you [reconfigure](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper.reconfigure) that property it'll change how strings are encoded when printed:

```
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='latin-1')
```

Alternatively, you could encode the string yourself and then write the bytes to stdout's underlying binary [buffer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.buffer).

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write("<some text>".encode('latin-1'))
```

Beware that `buffer` is not a public property: "This is not part of the TextIOBase API and may not exist in some implementations."